# Rust cannot infer type in closure

Tags: rust, closures, type-inference

Consider the following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v: Vec<f32> = vec![0.0];
    let foo_a: f32 = (|i| v[i])(0); // This works

    let v: Vec<(f32, f32)> = vec![(0.0, 0.0)];
    let foo_b: f32 = (|i| v[i].0)(0); // This doesn't work

    let foo_c: f32 = (|i| v[i as usize].0)(0); // This works
}
```

`foo_a` and `foo_c` pass compilation, however `foo_b` produces an error. For some reason, when you try to index a vector of things that are not primitives, in a closure, the compiler cannot infer the type of `v[i]` - the things that you are trying to index.

Error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:6:27
  |
6 |     let foo_b: f32 = (|i| v[i].0)(0); // This doesn't work
  |                           ^^^^ cannot infer type
```

Notice that if you don't use a closure, or you manually specify the type of `i`, or you use a vector/slice of primitives the error goes away.

What is so special about `foo_b` that doesn't allow the compiler to infer `v[i]`?

Comment: Closure type inference is quirky. It works the best when the closure is passed into a function and we know the type it expects (this is the most common case, so this is the case the Rust compiler optimizes for). Other cases sometimes works and sometimes not. I don't know the exact details, though.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I guess that makes sense... This completely took me by surprise today though. If this is just a limitation of the closure's type inference system I can accept that.

Comment: Weird, even `(|i| v[i].0)(0_usize)` doesn't work. Inference is truly a strange beast.

Comment: Calling `get(i)` also doesn't work. However, I'm not sure what would satisfy you as an answer to this question. You can report this as an issue in https://github.com/rust-lang/rust. How can we at SO help you?